# Getting FileNotFoundError: when trying to read a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a csv file but i am getting bellow error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'E:\\Data_sheet\naukri_com_job_sample.csv' does not exist: b'E:\\Data_sheet\naukri_com_job_sample.csv
```

Since i am running python from different directory i have provided full path but still getting error. Below is my command.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("E:\Data_sheet\naukri_com_job_sample.csv",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

But at the same time if i am trying to access other csv file in same location i am not seeing the error.

```
df = pd.read_csv("E:\Data_sheet\ICC_Test_Batting_Figures_2.csv",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

I am just changing the file name and getting the error. Please let me know what is the issue

Comment: What is the output of:  `import os`, then `naukri_com_job_sample.csv in os.listdir(r'E:\Data_sheet')`?

Comment: Hi Erfan below is the output. I can see my desired file
['ICC Test Bat 3001.xlsx',
 'ICC_Test_Batting_Figures.csv',
 'ICC_Test_Batting_Figures_2.csv',
 'jobs-on-naukricom',
 'naukri_com_job_sample.csv',
 'Sample..csv',
 'untitled0.py']